# Wrong Universal Time Wordpress

Tags: timezones

My problem,

I have a problem in the time zone, this is seen in "Universal time" on my WordPress general settings page. Universal time is the same as local time.

[image]

And this causes constraints on the date of publication of the article, including if you want to schedule a post. And when I published the article, the date information showed it was posted 7 hours ago. Even though I just published.

Note :
I have set php.ini (date.timezone = Asia / Jakarta).

Please help.

Comment: Site Health Status :

PHP default timezone was changed after WordPress loading by a date_default_timezone_set() function call. This interferes with correct calculations of dates and times.

Comment: You shouldn’t set the Timezone in php.ini the way you have. Try setting it back to UTC.

Comment: No changes.......